# cURL error 60 Wordpress running on localhost

Tags: wordpress, ssl, curl, localhost

The error message I get when I fire up *flywheel local* with a brand new wordpress site on my local windows PC, is this:

**cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem**

I installed Local v5.10.1 then started a new site. Afterwards any plugin installed gives this error. I tried installing *Simple SSL* but this gave the same error. As there is no content and this is the standard twenty-twenty-one theme as it comes out of the box.

This error does not appear on my older sites I created, only on any new ones I start. So now so I'm not sure why SSL works for the older sites and not for the new sites. Simple SSL has always allowed me to develop locally without issues and not this weird error just popped up. Maybe it is something to do with the latest wordpress version?
(The previous sites use `v5.6.2` and the new sites uses wordpress `5.7` which may be giving the issue? Has anyone else seen anything like this?

**Wordpress setup info:**

```
Web Server: nginx
PHP: 7.3.5
DB: MySQL 8.0.16
Wordpress: 5.7
```