# Wordpress cUrl error 60 and 77 - Nothing seems to work

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Over the few past months I've been building websites with wordpress and today I've stumbled upon a new error that I cant' understand.

**Error. Could not connect to update server (cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem
CApath: none).**

Now, I do know what curl is and all that. But what I do not understand is that this error is ONLY for this one project and not the other 30 projects in the same folder. On top of this this error persist both locally and on the live version.

Here's what I've tried:

- Changing PHP version
- Replaced .pem with .crt and even with .txt at the very back
- renamed the cacert.pem file
- reinstalled wp
- restarted pc just in case
- copied same plugin from an other project to see if current was corrupt
- made sure the path was correct

Here is my php ini:

**curl.cainfo ="/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem"**

**openssl.cafile= "/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem"**

Oh and I also know what the errors stand for.

I am working on a mac for the first time but I've never had any issues with this plugin or curl. First time. Any suggestions on what to do next?

The plugin I am mentioning is Advanced Custom Fields Pro - Error only persists on the UPDATE page of that plugin. It does not show up anywhere else.

The PLUGIN can update even though the error 60 tells me that it has issues connecting to update server. This is what makes me consider this as a visual error.

Comment: Found a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66690025/curl-error-60-wordpress-running-on-localhost

Comment: This might be related to the recent [expiration of a Lets Encrypt root certificate](https://www.theregister.com/2021/09/30/lets_encrypt_xero_slack_outages/)?

Comment: @KenY-N Could very well be. I forgot to mention in the post (will add it in a sec) that the plugin allows itself to update so it does have connection with curl. The error also seems to be a visual error only. Great catch, might consider that being the issue although my older projects do not have the error. When I say older I mean like... 2 months old at most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the expired DST Root CA X3, which expired Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT.

The DST CA Root X3 certificate is part of the "cacert-bundle".
As of today the "cacert-bundle" can be found here: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
as part of the bundle https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem.

The expired certificate is:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
    44:af:b0:80:d6:a3:27:ba:89:30:39:86:2e:f8:40:6b
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: O=Digital Signature Trust Co., CN=DST Root CA X3
Validity
    Not Before: Sep 30 21:12:19 2000 GMT
    Not After : Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
    Subject: O=Digital Signature Trust Co., CN=DST Root CA X3
    Subject Public Key Info:
    Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
    Public-Key: (2048 bit)
```

Which is used to verify peer in curl calls to websites using Let's Encrypt issued certificates.

Here's a detailed solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69411107/1549092

Let's Encrypt formal address of the issue can be found here: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/